# UseDefaultCredentials with Exchange Web Services

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm a pretty new programmer. One of the things I've been tasked with at work is getting our custom tools to create draft emails and drop them into the draft email folder of the user running the tool. We presently use Exchange Server 2010 (but are in the process of migrating over to Exchange Online).

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.iewshttpwebrequest.usedefaultcredentials%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) talks about a UseDefaultCredentials but I can't seem to work out how to implement it. I created an ExchangeService object called service and managed to interact with our Exchange server using this for credentials:

service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("my login name", "my password");

I'd like to be able to eliminate that from the code and have it use the credentials of the logged-in user who is using the tool. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use the defaultcredentials you can eliminate your posted code. Just set "UseDefaultCredentials" to True and don't set the Credentials manually. In this case the credentials of the User who is running your tool will be taken. I use that on my own and it works finde for me.

Greets, J